# browserify + gulp + react cannot find module react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp, ubuntu-14.04, browserify

I started to work on a new project and I need to set up the environment. All the others team members work with a OS X environment while I'm using Ubuntu 14. The project is already working for them but I'm having problems setting up.

I'm getting this error when I try to run

```
$ gulp watch
Cannot find module 'React' from '/home/camilatigre/dev/kahuso/kahuso-ux/scripts/components/company/dashboard'`
```

And if I try to run `browserify` I also get a similar error:

```
$ browserify -t reactify ./scripts/app.jsx > app.js
Error: Cannot find module 'React' from '/home/camilatigre/dev/kahuso/kahuso-ux/scripts/components/company/dashboard'
at /home/camilatigre/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
at process (/home/camilatigre/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
at ondir (/home/camilatigre/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
at load (/home/camilatigre/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
at onex (/home/camilatigre/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
at /home/camilatigre/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

I already tried to reinstall npm, nodejs, browserify, reactify, clean the node_modules folder and re-add all the packages but nothing works.

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: where is the react module actually?

Comment: What command do you use to install the packages? Also, to make sure, it is asking you about `React`, not `Reactify`

Comment: npm install react @MatthewHerbst

Comment: kahuso/kahuso-ux/node_modules/ here are all modules @antman

Comment: @CamilaTigre are you installing all this globally or local to your project as dependencies or devDependencies

Comment: It doesn't look like gulp is pointed at react in node_modules... you can try to add gulp-react, and then edit the gulp config accordingly... http://tylermcginnis.com/reactjs-tutorial-pt-2-building-react-applications-with-gulp-and-browserify/

Comment: @Vish I already tried local and global. everything installed with npm

Comment: @CamilaTigre can you post the gulp.js and the package.json file and confirm if the node modules folder in the project has react installed.

Comment: thank you everyone that tried to help me ((:

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution. 2 archives were using a `require('React')` when it should be a lowercase `r`.